# How do I make ifconfig/dhclient setting permanent in FreeBSD?

Tags: wireless-networking, virtual-machine, freebsd, wifi-configuration, ifconfig

Lately, for the purpose of smoke-testing the Perl 5 core distribution, I have been using VirtualBox to install VMs of various versions of FreeBSD on a Linux x86_64 host.

In my first attempt at doing so, I followed the (very good) instructions provided by the FreeBSD Foundation on installing that in a virtual box.  I downloaded `FreeBSD-10.3-RELEASE-amd64-disc1.iso` and use it for the basis of creating a VBox.  I don't recall the exact steps I took to guarantee that the VM had network access, but I do know that I have been able to use customary network programs (ping, scp, sftp, curl, git, ...) successfully.

Today I needed to install a more recent version of FreeBSD, FreeBSD-12.0-CURRENT.  This version does not have a .iso file yet, so I worked from `FreeBSD-12.0-CURRENT-amd64.vmdk.xz`.  After de-compressing that file I used the instructions [here](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/open-vmdk-virtualbox-28847.html) to create a new VM, I successfully booted FreeBSD-12.0-CURRENT, but it quickly became apparent that I did not have Internet access.  'ping' failed to find google.com.

Following the instructions [here](http://zfsguru.com/doc/bsd/setup) as root I called `ifconfig`, called `dhclient em0`, then noted that I now had internet access.  I was then able to call `pkg install pkg` and proceed from there to install other packages.  I added a non-root user, logged out as root and logged in as that user, and noted that that user had Internet access as well.

I then powered down the VM.  When I rebooted, I discovered that I no longer had network access.  As root, I once again called `dhclient em0` and got Internet access for both users.

So what I want to learn is how to retain the effect of `dhclient em0` permanently -- i.e., across shutdowns and reboots of the VM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that adding `ifconfig_em0="DHCP"` to `/etc/rc.conf` should suit your needs.

This way the `em0` interface will try to automatically connect to the network.

See the [**29.3.3.1.2 Basic Settings** chapter in the FreeBSD handbook](http://www.pl.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-wireless.html) for more information.